# C# Eval() support

Tags: c#, eval

we need to evaluate a value in an object in run time while we have a textual statement of the exact member path for example: **myobject.firstMember.secondMember[3].text**
we thought of parsing this textual statement using regex and then evaluate the text value by using reflection but before we do that i wonder if C# support some kind of **eval** ability? so we won't have to do the parsing ourself. How do microsoft do this in their immediate window or watch windows?

thanks you very much,

Adi Barda

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx) from System.Web.UI:

```
var foo = new Foo() { Bar = new Bar() { Value = "Value" } };
var value = DataBinder.Eval(foo, "Bar.Value");
```

Comment: do you by chance have a similar solution that works under .Net Core / .Net or even .Net Standard?

Answer (score 19):

I have written an open source project, [Dynamic Expresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/), that can convert text expression written using a C# syntax into delegates (or expression tree). Expressions are parsed and transformed into [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) without using compilation or reflection.

You can write something like:

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
var result = interpreter.Eval("8 / 2 + 2");
```

or

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter()
                .SetVariable("service", new ServiceExample());

string expression = "x > 4 ? service.SomeMethod() : service.AnotherMethod()";

Lambda parsedExpression = interpreter.Parse(expression, 
                        new Parameter("x", typeof(int)));

parsedExpression.Invoke(5);
```

My work is based on Scott Gu article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx .

Comment: This is super interesting. I tried this on your web demo but got error "Expression expected": [1,2,3].Sum()

Comment: @ShitalShah Array declaration are not supported. You can call Sum on an array created with a function or from a parameter/variable.

Answer (score 8):

In the future (around the 5.0 timeframe), the "compiler as a service" may be able to do this. Actually, you may be able to do a lot of this now with "mono" (see [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) and [Mono.CSharp](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp) - however, I expect it'll need to know a lot more about the context to be able to use local variables etc in [`Evaluate`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp)) - but there isn't any support for this in the current MS .NET offering.

For now, you would have to do something like what a lot of the data-binding code does... split it apart by tokens such as "." and use reflection. Strictly speaking, the binding code actually uses `TypeDescriptor`/`PropertyDescriptor` rather than direct reflection, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although a somewhat heavy-weight approach, you can use C# CodeDom to emit a new a new assembly that contains a method with just that line of code.

This is much more heavy-handed than some of the other suggestions, I admit, but on the other hand you let the C# parser do the heavy lifting, so it should be able to handle everything you throw at it as long as it's valid C#.

If you go that route, you also need to ensure that you can unload the emitted assembly again, so creating and unloading AppDomains may be necessary.

I have successfully implemented and used the above technique. On the other hand, if you can use a [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) it would be much more light-weight. However, I have never tried that approach, so I can't say whether you can implement a DynamicMethod's body using C# literals.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the expression evaluation and rules engine feature of Windows Workflow Foundation can do things like this. See [Introduction to the Windows Workflow Foundation Rules Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554919.aspx).

One interesting thing about these components is that they were designed so that you can host the design-time components in your own applications to design sets of rules and/or expressions that operate in the context of your own custom classes. For instance, you'd tell it to design an expression against "myObject", and it would know that there's a firstMember which has a secondMember which has an indexer yielding a type that has a text property. You can persist the expressions and rules as XML, and read them back at runtime, without needing to use the designer at runtime.

In particular, see [External RuleSet Toolkit Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472424.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can always try my light-weight C# Eval program. It compiles a substantial subset of the C# language to dynamic methods. Full details on my GitHub repository [DavidWynne/CSharpEval](https://github.com/DavidWynne/CSharpEval)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, C# doesn't have any native facilities for doing exactly what you are asking.

However, my C# eval program does allow for evaluating C# code. It provides for evaluating C# code at runtime and supports many C# statements, including expressions like "**myobject.firstMember.secondMember[3].text**". In fact, this code is usable within any .NET project, however, it is limited to using C# syntax. Have a look at my website, http://csharp-eval.com, for additional details.

Comment: The website still exists, but is no longer functional

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such built-in Eval function. You'll have to go the Regex+Reflection way. I also think that Visual Studio is doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar I'm using to find dynamically nested properties.. you'd need to addthe logic for indexers... and some extra checking...  i'm catching nulls/errors in my calling method...

```
  public static object FindDottedProperty(this object input, string propertyName)
  {
    if (input == null)
      return null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
      return null;

    Queue props = new Queue(propertyName.Split('.'));
    if (props.Count == 0) return null;

    //start with input object and roll out property stack from there.
    object ret = input;
    while (props.Count > 0)
    {
      var prop = props.Dequeue();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop)) return null;

      /*** ADD INDEXER LOGIC HERE ***/

      //get the property's value based on the current named item
      ret = ret.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(ret, null);

      if (null.Equals(ret)) return null;
    }

    //return looked up value
    return ret;
  }
```