# C# .NET 4.0 expression eval

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, function, eval

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C# eval equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/c-eval-equivalent)
>   [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-expression-dynamically)

How can I evaluate a valid C# code and get results inside a compiled program (dynamically)?
I know this is not very clear, i'll try to show that with a code snippet:

Visual C# 2010.

```
double x = 3.0;//this is function argument, we'll take 3
string str = "Math.Pow(x,2)+2*x+4";//value with written function in C#,equals: x^2+2x+4
double y = eval(str);
/* this is the idea! something like JS.I want to make string parsed into parameter,i.e
y=19 - this is what double y should became after eval(str) */
```

Hope you got the idea.

Thanks.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024070/c-eval-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, LINQ won't do this for you.

The closest you can easily get at the moment is to use [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) which allows you to compile a whole assembly - but you'll need to wrap your expression in all the other source code required to make it a complete class.