# Is it possible to modify a code at runtime in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to create a smart calculator....other than user defined routines to solve 
maths equations ...like

```
private int  add(int num1,int num2)
{
   return x+y;
}
```

//in this case the user should enter two numbers and press the add key(if using GUI)

but i want to tell my calculator how to handle the calculation at run-time.
rather than having a fixed  number of routines ,,
i would like  to add user defined functions...or routines at runtime
any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024070/c-sharp-eval-support) and see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSharpCodeProvider` and `ILGenerator` will both let you generate code at runtime... that said  creating code at runtime doesn't seem to make much sense to me for your use case.